# How to stream music in default player in the background Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background, stream, default

I have small problem with stream music from internet in the default player when activity is minimized.

Code below works fine, but only when Activity is on screen:

```
public void Relax(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://example.com/sample.mp3"), "audio/mp3");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Is any way to stream it when user click home button and want to do other things? Preferably without creating own Media Player. I was trying with AsyncTask but with no success.